# CSS let input consume available width

Tags: css, text, input

I have the following markup as a base:

```
<div>
    <span>some dynamic text</span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

I want the input to be displayed in a line with the text (which is always a single line but varying in length) and consume the available width according to the text length. the markup can be changed if required. both elements should be 100% of the parent element's width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two methods I can think of:

#### The first one:

You can simulate the behavior of a table using CSS;

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "text">Glee is awesome!</div>
    <div class = "inputtext"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /*how much should both the text and the input take*/
}
.container .text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px; /*make sure it's only as wide as needed*/
}
.container .inputtext {
    display: table-cell;
}
.container input {
    width: 100%; /*let the input take all available space*/
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/qRwGa/).

#### The second one:

This method relies on floating:

HTML:

```
<div class = "text">Glee is awesome!</div>
<div class = "inputtext"><input type = "text" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    float: left;
}
.inputtext {
    overflow: hidden; /*this is the key here*/
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Another little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/aY6Wf/).

Comment: basically it's working great, just one unlovely thing: the right border of the input is missing. seems it's like 1px too wide or so: see here http://jsfiddle.net/AWHEn/1/

Comment: @AndreasLinden Yes, that's because the width is set to `100%` then you're adding a `1px` border, so there's a `2px` overflow. You can set width to `99%` instead, I don't know whether that's good enough. I'll continue looking for something more beautiful.

Comment: @j08691 Nothing :) I just thought of this one as well and thought I might post it, too.

Comment: @j08691 Updated the answer to contain both methods now.

Comment: @AndreasLinden @j08691 Okay, I couldn't think of any way but setting `width: 99%`. Sorry :( Of course, one way would be to avoid setting a border altogether.

Comment: @Abody97 I'll check if the display table solution works better concerning the missing right border...